# Complex integration $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{cx}}{1+e^x}\,dx$ for $c \in (0,1)$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I have to calculate real integral $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{cx}}{1+e^x} \, \text{d}x$ for $c \in (0,1)$.
I have also hint, to integrate over the squere, which consists of $x$ axis, 2 lines paralel to $y$ axis, and line with $z=x+2\pi i$, for real $x$.

I think that idea is to use Residue theorem. I think, that for the function $\frac{e^{cz}}{1+e^z}$, all singularities are $z=\pi i+2k\pi i$, so the only one within the area is $2 \pi i$. But I am not sure how to calculate residue in this point, neither how to evaluate other $3$ integrals on rectangle. I have concluded, that both integrals on the vertical line cancel each other, becouse:
$$
\lim_{A \to \infty} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{cA}e^{ix}}{1+e^Ae^{ix}} \, \text{d}x=0
$$
and
$$
\lim_{A \to \infty} \int_{2\pi}^0 \frac{e^{-cA}e^{ix}}{1+e^{-A} e^{ix}} \, \text{d}x=0
$$
How to determine integral on the other horizontal line?

Comment: A pole occurs where $1+e^z=0,$ which is where $e^z=-1,$ and that happens where $z=\pi i$ and at other points differing from that by integer multiples of $2\pi i.$ It seems you're integrating over a square, and only one of those points is in the interior of that square.

Comment: This problem has already a few duplicates, look [1][1], [2][2], [3][3] and probably many others.

  [1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/643287/399263
  [2]: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1715376/399263
  [3]: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/130472/399263

Comment: $$\begin{align}
& 1+e^z = 1 + e^{z-\pi i} e^{\pi i} \\ {} \\
= {} & 1 - e^{z-\pi i} = 1 -\left( 1 +(z-\pi i) + \frac {(z-\pi i)^2} 2 + \cdots \right) \\ {} \\
= {} & -(z-\pi i)\left( 1 - \frac{z-\pi i} 2 + \text{higher-degree terms} \right)
\end{align}$$
And so:
$$
\frac{e^{cz}}{1 + e^z} = \frac{-e^{cz}}{1 - \frac{z-\pi i} 2 + \text{higher-degree terms}} \times \frac 1 {z-\pi i}
$$
The residue at $\pi i$ is the product of the value of the fraction to the left of $\text{“} {\times} \text{''}$ and the residue of the function of $z$ that is to the right of$\text{ “}{\times}\text{''.}$